# How to use conditional statements in mvc orderBy to move the 0 value last

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

super fresh coder here,

Currently I am using a foreach loop in my view to generate sections based on the model's position value. If the position is zero, the model is in development. I am trying to get the 0 values to show up last in an orderBy statement, but I can't seem to find the answer. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish my task? Here is my current syntax:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OredrBy( model => model.Position))
{
    <div></div>
}
```

Comment: If you want `0` to be last, try `OrderByDescending`, so that the largest values come first.

Answer (score 1):

`model => ( ( model.Position == 0 ) ? int.MaxValue : model.Position )`

Comment: This answer has been automatically flagged as low quality. I do think that if you provide some description on how your answer addresses the problem, OP and other with similar problems would learn from it, it would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help everyone, I actually managed to solve this myself. Keeps descending order, but puts zeros last.

My solution:

```cs
OrderBy(a => a.Position == 0).ThenBy(a => a.Position).ToArrayAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@{
    var orderedModel =  Model.OrderByDescending(model => model.Position).ToList();
    foreach(var item in orderedModel)
    {
        <div></div>
    }
}
```